# c++ unable to clear inputStream

Tags: c++, while-loop, inputstream

I am new to C++ and was attempting to create a basic program. To ask for two values and store the result in separate variables as shown below:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main () {

int sizeOfArray = -1, bufferSize = -1;

while (true){
cout << "Enter the size of the array: " << endl;
cin >> sizeOfArray;
if (cin.fail())
cin.clear();


cout << "Enter the size of the buffer (k): " << endl;
cin >> bufferSize;
if (cin.fail())
cin.clear();


if (sizeOfArray > 0 && bufferSize > 0){
break;
} 

}

 return 0;
}
```

However, when entering a value that is not of type int instead of clearing and asking for the next input I run into an infinite while loop as shown below:

> Enter the size of the array: 
>   Enter the size of the buffer (k): 
>   Enter the size of the array: 
>   Enter the size of the buffer (k): 
>   Enter the size of the array: 
>   Enter the size of the buffer (k): 
>   Enter the size of the array: 
>   Enter the size of the buffer (k): 
>   Enter the size of the array: 
>   Enter the size of the buffer (k): 
>   Enter the size of the array: 
>   Enter the size of the buffer (k): 
>   Enter the size of the array: 
>   Enter the size of the buffer (k): 
>   Enter the size of the array: 
>   Enter the size of the buffer (k): 
>   ^C

Comment: You also have to consume the wrong input to clear the input buffer.

Answer (score 1):

`cin.clear()` clears the state of `cin`. It does not remove the problematic input from the stream. You need to add code to ignore rest of the line.

```
if (cin.fail())
{
   cin.clear();
   cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}
```

Add

```
#include <limits>
```

to be able to use `std::numeric_limits`.

Read more about [`std::istream::ignore`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore).

Comment: @R Sahu Can you please explain this line to me        cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

Comment: @Sandup, added a link in the answer.

Comment: @R Sahu Ah i understand this now thank you

Comment: @Sandup, you're welcome. I'm glad I was able to help.